# How do I call functions in fragment from another?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I put two fragments in an activity. What I want to do is to hide a view from say fragment A when I click a button in fragment B. I have the hiding function in fragment A but how do I call it in fragment B?
I tried:

```
((FragmentA)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_a)).hideLivePreview();
```

but it gives me a null pointer exception...please help

Comment: you have to communicate with activity from fragment b, which will trigger function in fragment a. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity , check this link.

Comment: @Yashwanth Kumar  
thx man.. i am sure that's what I am supposed to do, but I am keep getting null pointer exceptions when I call function of fragment from activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not want to do this in general. Fragment A and Fragment B should not directly communicate, since Fragment A and Fragment B may not both be on the screen at the same time *all of the time*. They might be side-by-side on a large screen but displayed via separate activities on smaller screens. IMHO, activities should mediate all communications between fragments. If you have two fragments that are too tightly coupled for that, they should not be separate fragments in the first place.

All that being said, you are getting a `NullPointerException` because there is no fragment with that ID in the activity.

Comment: Thx! I will try to do in in the activity then.. but for the NullPointerException I did check for the activity before calling the function, so there should be such a fragment within the specific activity. Not sure if I misunderstood anything...