# what is the rigth way to call a function in one fragment from another fragemt?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can someone tell me what is the right way to call a function in one fragment from another fragment?
I passed the object of one fragment to another fragemnt as serializable. but I dont think thats the right way.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850583/how-do-i-call-functions-in-fragment-from-another) but the accepet answer just says activities should mediate all communications between fragments. can someone pls tell me what is the code to access an other fragment in the same activity by using activity as mediator?

Comment: Ultimus is right. check out this link for more details http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try reading the [Guide to using fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity).

If you want **Fragment_A** to comunicate with **Fragment_B**, you should define an interface inside
**Fragment_A** (which the parent activity has to implement) to send
data from **Fragment_A** to parent activity and from the parent activity send that data to **Fragment_B**.

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Create getter/setter methods for that shared Data in activity, In one fragment

```
((Appropriate Cast)getActivity).setSharedData(type Data)  // saves data to be shared
```

In other fragment

```
((Appropriate Cast )getActivity).getSharedData()   // returns shared data
```