# calling function of activity from fragment class gives NPE

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have an activity whose parent class is fragment let we call it fragment A, I have another fragment B from where I want to call the function of the activity related to fragment A, How to call this function? I have tried this:
Respond and SResponses are the activities whose function am calling.and these function are only called when these activites are in active state.

```
if (Respond.getActivityStatus() == true)
{   
if (Respond.getrthreadid().compareTo(threadid) == 0)                                                         
{   
//Respond res = new Respond();     
//res.notiffy(message);                                                 
((Respond)getActivity()).notiffy(message);                                      
}                                       
}               

if (SResponses.getActivityStatus() == true)                                         
{                                               
if (SResponses.getsrthreadid().compareTo(threadid) == 0)                                                
{                                           
//SResponses sres = new SResponses();                                      
//  sres.notiffy(message);                                  
((SResponses)getActivity()).notiffy(message);                                                                                                   
}                                               
}                                               
}

} catch (RuntimeException e) {

// TODO: handle exception                                               
e.printStackTrace();                                                
}                                               
}                                               

}

} catch (RuntimeException e) {

// TODO: handle exception                                       
e.printStackTrace();

}
```

But its giving me Null pointer exception. Please help.

Comment: You can use interface as a callback to the activity. show us some code. Also "I have an activity whose parent class is fragment ". Note fragment is hosted by a activity.

Comment: Add Null checks before your try to access the object

Comment: @Raghunandan check the edit and I know the fragment is hosted by activity . I have a fragment which starts another activity and I want to call the function of that activity from other fragment.

Comment: @user3091531 check the docs about fragments

Answer (score 2):

Your fragment is not always attached to an activity, so at times, getActivity() may return null.

Read about this [Coordinating With The Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

If you want fragment A to communicate with fragment B, you should define an interface inside   fragment A (which the parent activity has to implement) to send data from fragment A to parent activity and from the parent activity send that data to fragment B.

[Check this link.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

Comment: Also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850583/how-do-i-call-functions-in-fragment-from-another